# How to get qemu .cow2 actual file size

Tags: debian, qemu

qcow2 disk images can grow as data is added. This allows for smaller file sizes which is great, but how can I get actual size of the file system in order to define the disk size when adding it to virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `qemu-img info` for that:

```
$ qemu-img info fedora33.qcow2 
image: fedora33.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 30 GiB (32212254720 bytes)
disk size: 15.1 GiB
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    compression type: zlib
    lazy refcounts: true
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
    extended l2: false
```

where `virtual size` shows the size of the disk in the VM.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. I also found out that regardless of the defined hard disk size specified during creation, once mounted the correct value is also updated.